# Removing controls in windows form breaking for loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows form with code to dynamically create TextBoxes. When certain conditions are met, TextBoxes will be created, all of which with names starting with "TextBoxRep" and a unique ID attached at the back, for example "TextBoxRep112" or "TextBoxRep234".

Now, when these certain conditions are no longer met (which can happen), I want to be able to remove these TextBoxes. My current code is as follows:

```
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("LabelRep") Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
        End If

        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("TextBoxRep") Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(ctrl)
        End If
    Next
```

It essentially loops through every control in the Windows Form and if the control name starts with "TextBoxRep" I remove it from the list of controls.

The problem is, the remove() seems to be rather random. The controls are removed, but not all of them at the same time; sometimes, only some are removed and the loop must be run again and again for all the TextBoxes to be removed correctly. It actually seems like the For loop is being broken after some of the .Remove() function calls.

What's happening here?

Comment: Maybe the way the controls are being created in the form is the key to  find the error, Can you show it to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An essiantial problem is that you change the enumeration (`Me.Control`) while iterating through it. This skips every second control.

Your loop does the following:
Say your enumeration contains three controls, `Tb1, Tb2, Tb3`. At the start it looks like this:

**0**: Tb1, **1**: Tb2, **2**: Tb3

*Iteration 1*, loop is at index **0**:

`-->` Finds Tb1 at index **0**, Removes it `-->`

**0**: Tb2, **1**: Tb3

Loop goes to *iteration 2*, it is now at index **1**:

`-->` Finds Tb3 at index **1**, Removes it `-->`

**0**: Tb2

The loop now finds no more items after the current index, so it ends. Tb2 is left in the list.

Never change the enumeration while iterating through it! You can get away with it by starting at the last index and going forward while deleting, but its all kind of bad.
Instead first select the controls to remove and then remove them in a second go:

```
Dim ToRemove As New List(Of Control)
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (c) Is TextBox AndAlso c.Name.StartsWith("TextboxRep") Then ToRemove.Add(c)
Next
For Each c As Control In ToRemove
    Me.Controls.Remove(c)
Next
```

Comment: I can't believe I made such a fundamental error. Thank you for the quick reply. Although, your solution is like to create the exact same problem, but the theory above is correct, so I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: No it does not have the same error since the `ToRemove` list is not changed by deleting items from `Me.Controls`. Therefore every item is actually removed.

Comment: @Jens - I'm surprised that the original code didn't have some warning or error for altering the collection being iterated over.

Comment: @Jens that is a very good point. Guess I need to relearn my basics again. Thank you!